# Allow Azure database creation ONLY inside Elastic Pool

Tags: azure

In Azure, is there a way to create a custom role or enforce a policy to **only** allow users to create databases **inside** an elastic pool?

I tried with a custom role with the "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write" in "NotActions" section, but this permission is also needed to create databases inside Elastic Pool. I have not yet tried with policies, because i'm still learning how define them.

I also tried with "SQL Server Contributor" and "SQL DB Contributor" roles, but neither suits our needs.

The idea is to restrict the creation of new single databases, Sql servers or pools to certain users.

Comment: While you may not be able to prevent it, if you are concerned about how new databases are created, it may be worth creating a policy that flags and alerts when new databases are created so that they can be reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not currently possible to achieve this I'm afraid. The permissions and policies don't differentiate between a standalone DB and a pool.